# how to make a DIV responsive css html

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to make a div responsive for all the possibilities
html code . I am finding problem for 320*480

```
   <style>
  .in1{width:275px;height:45px; border-color: #f0b41c;}
   .in3{width:120px;height:40px;}
   .in4{ width:150px;height:40px;}

    </style>
  <div>         

 <input class="in1" type="text"  name="name" placeholder="your name" required>
  <input class="in1"  type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email" required>
  <input class="in3" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"><br>


     <span style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 130%;color: #fff;   padding: 10px;"> SOME TEXT <span style=" font-family: 'Grundschrift';color:#f0b41c;">Some Text</span> SOME TEXT</span>
     <br><input class="in4"  type="submit" name="submit" value="How to Play">  
         </div>
```

Comment: use percentage instead of px

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Brief your narration

Comment: as @Sam1604 say. What do you expect for a result. You got a answer with % for your inputs (that is responsive), if that isn't enough you have to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries, like this:

`@media screen and (device-width: 768px){
 /*Your style to be applied */
}`

You can refer [this link](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style>
  .in1{width:80%;height:45px; border-color: #f0b41c;}
   .in3{width:50%;height:40px;}
   .in4{ width:60%;height:40px;}

    </style>
```

Comment: Just by changing the width is that enough ? no its not working just the size of trxt box is increased

Comment: it is just an example set percentage according to your need

Comment: Thanks for the answer got to know how important is % than px